# Multi Searching string in a txt file and count

Tags: search, count, autohotkey

```
$^F8::
File := "*.txt"             ;can include directory -- * is wildcard
FileHit := ""               ;for reading .txt file
ArrayName:= []
ArrayName[1]:= "CAM_NWID=ESH050RN"
ArrayName[2]:= "CAM_NWID=ESH012RW"
ArrayName[3]:= "CAM_NWID=ESH016RN"
ArrayName[4]:= "CAM_NWID=ESH027RN"

ArrayValue:=[]
ArrayStore:=[]
ArrayValue[j] := A_LoopField
ArrayValue[j, k] := A_LoopReadLine
ArrayCount := 0

InputBox, Directory, Enter the searched directory, Leave empty to use the current directory. Subfolders will 

be also searched., , 300, 150
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Query canceled.
    Exit
}

Directory := RegExReplace(Directory, "\\$") ; Removes the leading backslash, if present.

If Directory
{
    If(!InStr(FileExist(Directory), "D"))
    {
        msgbox Invalid directory
        Exit
    }
    StringRight, DirectoryEndingChar, Directory, 1
    If(DirectoryEndingChar != "\")
        Directory .= "\"
}


Loop, %Directory%%File%, , 1
{
   FileRead, FileCheck, %A_LoopFileLongPath%
   IfInString, FileCheck, %StringCheck%
      FileHit%A_Index% := A_LoopFileLongPath
}

Loop,%Directory%%File%, *.txt, FR
{

for key, val in ArrayName


    Loop, Read, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, objects.txt
    {
    
        IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, % val
        {
            StringReplace, CurrentLine, A_LoopReadLine, Name(wstring:64)=
            FileAppend, %CurrentLine%`n
            vText := CurrentLine
            StrReplace(vText, CurrentLine, "", vCount)
            ;;MsgBox, % CurrentLine" = " .vCount 
        
        If (CurrentLine = CurrentLine)
        {
        ArrayValue[key,k]:=ArrayValue.Insert(key,A_LoopReadLine) ;;this should be the the point where I can pass the value to another specific index in other array
        }


ArrayCount+=1
ArrayValue[ArrayCount]
}
}


Loop % ArrayCount
{
element := ArrayValue[A_Index]
MsgBox % "Element Number " . A_Index . " is " . ArrayValue[A_Index]
}
}
return
```

- I was not able to pass the value into the other array(ArrayValue) so
  that i can keep track of the counts
- MY Goal: Read folder with all text file
- Search sets of Array inside the text file (which is the strings)
- Everytime it matches should add +1 to the counter
- Then Print in order the results in notepad

  ex.

  CAM_NWID=050RN = 10 

  CAM_NWID=012RW = 2 

  CAM_NWID=016RN = 6 

  CAM_NWID=027RN = 1